# Mortarboard badge

Tags: support, reputation, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I got this badge today, does this mean I should stop trying to get my rep up for the day? 
What will happen to the upvotes and accepted answers after I hit the quota? Will I get them tomorrow? How would I know when the timer is reset?

Comment: Just realized that the Mortarboard badge can quell the "why am I not getting any more repz today‽" questions.

Answer (score 2):

You won't get any more than 200 rep from votes, but can get even more from accepted answers. SOFU is not about trying to get your rep for the day but about helping others, btw.

Comment: Yes, I know that :) ofcourse!!! but...it kind of felt like I was on crack when I couldn't step away from this site.

Comment: @Voodoo: It *is* crack, and it's too late, you're addicted.